# How can I colorize <b-icon> component in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, colors, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue, bootstrap-icons

I use bootstrap-vue in my nuxt project and bootstrap-vue-icons for icons. Everything works nicely, but I can't colorize my icons.

Plugin import:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { BootstrapVue, BootstrapVueIcons } from 'bootstrap-vue'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(BootstrapVueIcons)
```

Icon component:

```
<b-icon variant="danger" icon="check-circle"></b-icon>
```

`package.json`:

```
"bootstrap-vue": {
      "version": "2.23.1",
      "requires": {
        "@nuxt/opencollective": "^0.3.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
        "vue-functional-data-merge": "^3.1.0"
      }
    },
```

I have tried as variant prop either dynamically binding color styles, it has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this:
Notic `variant="danger"` gives the red color by default. [Watch this](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/icons#variants)
you can add id and style it with css like:

```
<b-icon `variant="danger"` id="danger_icon" icon="check-circle"  ></b-icon>

#danger_icon{
  color:blue;
}
```

or change the default `variant="danger"` which is a class `.text-danger` color using css again

```
`<b-icon variant="danger" icon="check-circle"  ></b-icon>`

.text-danger {
color: black !important;
```

}

Watch this demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anq6zpek/1/)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have already tried that, i understand that should work, but it didn't. Maybe there some versions problem, but now i just use default bootstrap icons <i class="bi bi-bar-chart"></i>